# How to make content dynamic without changing DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a MVVM set up to switch between views. To accomodate for the design, the MainWindow holds a tabcontroller which shows a page accordingly. One of the inner pages is changed when the user presses a button. A visual representation of the setup:
[image: A visual representation of the setup]

I set a `Presenter` viewmodel to as the datacontext of `StudentView` to handle the button event thrown in `StudentOverview`. That works, but when I want to switch the view I have to set a new datacontext of a specific type. But since `Presenter` is my datacontext, switching it removes the button's functionality.

*What I want* is to change the datatemplate without relying on the datacontext.

## StudentView.xaml

```
<Page {...}>
    
    <Page.DataContext>
        <viewModels:Presenter/>
    </Page.DataContext>
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Overview" DataType="{x:Type models:StudentOverviewModel}">
            <local:StudentOverview/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Add" DataType="{x:Type models:StudentAddModel}">
            <local:AddStudentControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
</Page>
```

## StudentView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class StudentView : Page
    {
        public StudentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // This switches the view but disables the button
            this.DataContext = new StudentOverviewModel();

            if (this.DataContext is Presenter presenter)
            {
                presenter.PropertyChanged += (object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    // This switches the view but disables the button
                    this.DataContext = new StudentAddModel();
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just make two different versions of `StudentOverviewModel`, that inherit from the same base class. Use the base class as the variable name and expose one instance or the other. The View can decide if it wants to have seperate Templates or not, but you propably want to make a Template for each type. | Of course, this could be one of those rare cases where the button actually is a ViewOnly thing, no something the ViewModel should care about.

Comment: I re-read, and you exactly do not want to use subclassing. Well, there are at least 3 ways to skin that particular Feline: https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/3-ways-dynamic-data-templates/ only one of wich is the template selector. | However I think the button should be part of Studen View, given that it replaces the instance Displayed inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest two solutions:

First solution (recommended) would be to add a `SelectedContent` property  of type `object` (or any other common base type for all view models e.g., `IContentModel`) to the `Presenter` view model. Then bind the `SelectedContent` to the `ContentPresenter.Content` property:

**Presenter.cs**

```
public partial class Presenter : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Presenter()
  {
    // Set default content
    this.SelectedContent = new StudentOverviewModel();
  }

  private object selectedContent;
  public object SelectedContent
  {
    get => this.selectedContent; 
    set
    { 
      this.selectedContent = value; 
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  // Use ICommand implementation like DelegateCommand
  public ICommand LoadContentCommand => new LoadContentCommand(ExecuteLoadContent, CanExecuteLoadContent);

  private void ExecuteLoadContent(object param)
  {
    // Do something ...

    // Load the new content on Button clicked
    this.SelectedContent = new StudentAddModel();
  }

  private bool CanExecuteLoadContent => true;
}
```

**StudentView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class StudentView : Page
{
  public StudentView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}
```

**StudentView.xaml**

```
<Page {...}>
  <Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:Presenter/>
  </Page.DataContext>
  <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:StudentOverviewModel}">
      <local:StudentOverview/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate ="{x:Type models:StudentAddModel}">
      <local:AddStudentControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>

  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedContent}"/>
</Page>
```

**StudentOverview.xaml**

```
<UserControl{...}>

  <!--- content -->

  <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StudentView}}, Path=DataContext.LoadContentCommand}"/>
</UserControl>
```

You can safely remove the `Key` attribute of the `DataTemplate` (if the `DataType` is not the same) so that they will apply automatically to any matching data type (implicit `DataTemplate`).

---

Another solution would be to move the `SelectedContent` to `StudentView` and turn it into a `DependencyProperty`:

**StudentView.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class StudentView : Page
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SelectedContent", 
    typeof(object), 
    typeof(StudentView));

  public object SelectedContent
  {
    get => GetValue(SelectedContentProperty); 
    set => SetValue(SelectedContentProperty, value); 
  }

  public StudentView()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // This switches the view without disabling the button
    this.SelectedContent = new StudentOverviewModel();

    if (this.DataContext is Presenter presenter)
    {
      presenter.PropertyChanged += (object o, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
      {
        // This switches the view without disabling the button
        this.SelectedContent = new StudentAddModel();               
      };
    }
  }
}
```

**StudentView.xaml**

```
<Page {...}>
  <Page.DataContext>
    <viewModels:Presenter/>
  </Page.DataContext>
  <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:StudentOverviewModel}">
      <local:StudentOverview/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate ="{x:Type models:StudentAddModel}">
      <local:AddStudentControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Page.Resources>

  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type StudentView}}, Path=SelectedContent}"/>
</Page>
```

Comment: I tried to implement your first approach. Now the only question I have left is: "How do I make the view reload?". I've confirmed that the SelectedContent changes on buttonclick but there is no visual feedback.

Comment: Can you check the binding on the ContentPresenter? It looks like it doesn't point to the proper context and their failed to reference the SelectedContent property. You can check the output Windows for binding errors after enabling the appropriate WPF trace levels in the Debug settings. Does the view ever show the content? Is it always blank?

Comment: In StudentView my Binding is as follows: `<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedContent}"/>`. This is accompanied with an event handler in the codebehind solely to check if the code functions. Here I just execute a console writeline when PropertyChanged is invoked. That works.

Comment: I should add that the UserControl is indeed visible on load, I've also tried swapping the usercontrols in code and when doing so I do see the view that I expect. Regarding that the code just works, but I have a feeling that the window has to be reloaded somehow even though WPF shouldn't work that way.

Comment: Okay, let summarize it: everything works as expected, the initial content is showing and also the content changes on button click. Now you have the feeling that before the changes are visible you need to reload the Window? Are you sure? How do you reload the Window?

Comment: A video of the current behaviour: https://youtu.be/YWVSD_aMcuk
When pressing the button "Nieuwe Cursist" the view should be changed but it does not as of this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202568/discussion-between-demien-drost-and-bioniccode).

Comment: Your `PropertyChanged` invocator has a typo. You misspelled the property name. Change. See my comment in our chat.